# Adding and sorting elements of multidimensional list in a certain way

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, filter

I am working on this

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, date=0, product_name=0,qty=0,supplier=0):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.date = date
        self.qty = qty
        self.supplier= supplier
        self.my_list = []

    def purchase(self, date, product_name, qty, supplier_name ):
         self.my_list.append([supplier_name,date,product_name,qty])

    def calculation(self):
        for i in self.my_list:
           print(i)


choice=None
p=Product()
while True:
    choice=int(input("1 for the add record\n2 For the display result.\n"))
    if choice == 1:
        product_name=input("Enter the product name\n")
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty.\n"))
        date= input("Enter the date")
        supplier_name = input("Enter the supplier name.\n ")
        p.purchase(date,product_name,qty, supplier_name)

    elif choice == 2:
        p.calculation()
```

after executing this i have added data like this... when we choose 2 number option i am having data like this

```
eg.[supplier_name, date, product_name, quantity]

[supplierA, 2019-01-01, pencil, 20]
[supplierA, 2019-01-01, pencil, 30]
[supplierA, 2018-02-02, pen, 20]
[supplierB, 2017-02-02, scale, 10]
[supplierB, 2017-10-10, scale, 20]
[supplierC, 2019-01-01, pencil,10]
[supplierC, 2019-01-01, pencil,10]
[supplierC, 2019-01-01, pencil,10]
```

I want to filter this data in a way that if date and product name are same, its quantity should be added. and it must be group by supplier name .I means only individual supplier's date and qty be added in

```
expected output is 

Supplier A:
[2019-01-01, pencil, 50]
[2018-02-02, pen, 20]

Supplier B:
[2017-02-02, scale, 10]
[2017-10-10, scale, 20]

Supplier C:
[2019-01-01, pencil, 30]
```

i have tried with lambda and filter but could not able to make it. any idea how to make it possible?

Comment: You are looking for specific function ?,
This could be done by modifying Purchase method

Comment: You should consider using a dedicated library like `pandas` for this.

Comment: @VikrantPawar no specific function, but anything that brings the expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

this will work i think:

```
class Product:
    #init
    def __init__(self, date=0, product_name=0,qty=0,supplier=0):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.date = date
        self.qty = qty
        self.supplier= supplier
        #make self.my_dict
        self.my_dict={}

    def purchase(self, date, product_name, qty, supplier_name ):
        #make a new key if needing
         try:
             #add the data to the list
             self.my_dict[supplier_name].append([date,product_name,qty])
         except:
             #make a new list with data
             self.my_dict[supplier_name] = [[date,product_name,qty]]

    def calculation(self):
        #getting keys
        for i in list(self.my_dict):
            #print key
            print(i)
            #get items
            for k in self.my_dict[i]:
                #print item
                print(k)


choice=None
p=Product()
while True:
    choice=int(input("1 for the add record\n2 For the display result.\n"))
    if choice == 1:
        product_name=input("Enter the product name\n")
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty.\n"))
        date= input("Enter the date")
        supplier_name = input("Enter the supplier name.\n ")
        p.purchase(date,product_name,qty, supplier_name)

    elif choice == 2:
        p.calculation()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also modify existing purchase method :

```
def purchase(self, date, product_name, qty, supplier_name ):
    for item in self.my_list:
        if item[2] == product_name and item[1] == date and item[0] == supplier_name:
            item[3] = item[3] + qty
            return
    self.my_list.append([supplier_name,date,product_name,qty])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

    def calculation(self):
        # sort and group items by supplier_name, date, product_name
        x = groupby(sorted(self.my_list, key=itemgetter(slice(None, 3))), itemgetter(slice(None, 3)))
        # sum the quantities
        y = [i + [sum(map(itemgetter(3), j))] for i, j in x]
        # group items by supplier
        z = [(i, list(map(itemgetter(slice(1, None)), j))) for i, j in groupby(y, itemgetter(0))]
        # output
        for supplier, values in z:
            print("{0}:".format(supplier))
            print("\n".join(map(str, values)))
```